# Switch between the display of multiple monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-10, laptop-display

I've got Windows 10 and a Intel graphic card. Sometimes I have to connect various monitors to my laptop and I don't always have a clear view of all of them.

Is it possible to have the option to see the display (contents) of any monitor *in* the main monitor?

In other words, can I switch the view of the main monitor so I can access the view of the others from it?  Or perhaps see a scaled-down
view of another monitor in a window on the main monitor?

Answer (score 1):

[MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) has a scaled LivePreview and you can also move windows between the different screens.